# Install Samsung Android Note 2 MTP INF driver for Win XP in to Win7 - Win10 is using the same exact driver?

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, mtp, inf

I am troubleshooting Windows 7 64-bit MTP support for Samsung Note 2 with DN4 ROM.

Those who Google Samsung android MTP support for Win 7 will discover that this is a very long standing and unsolved issue. I have tried many solutions found through Google in the past few years without success. I think (but can not confirm this) that using custom ROM just make it worse.

However, I am also testing Win 10 Insider copy. And to my surprise, MTP (and PTP) works there without fuss. Troubleshooting and tracing the driver used in Win 10 result to inf files which can be found at the end of this post.

Base on the INF, driver used on Win10 is actually an older version (DriverVer=02/16/2012,2.9.317.0215) for Win XP, which can be downloaded [here](http://drivers.softmenu.org/download/driver-samsung-mobile-mtp-device-driver-2.9.317.215-download-1750957.html). Unfortunately I am getting this error

> `The driver installation file for this device is missing a necessary entry. This may be because the INF was written for Windows 95 or later. Contact your hardware vendor.`

Method of installation. In Device Manager, right click the MTP device with exclamation mark icon. Select "Update Driver Software" then click "Browse my computer for driver software". Then click "Let me pick from list of device drivers on my computer" and browse for downloaded driver for file `ssudmtp.inf`.

QUESTION: 
If MS can make it work for Win 10 64-bit, surely it works for  Win 7 64-bit. (Bitness is not an issue here since the inf did has support for AMD64). Anyone with knowledge and experience of hacking inf to work with Win 7? Appreciate tips on how to make this inf and driver install in Win 7.

```
;******************************************************************************************
;
; Name:  ssudmtp.inf
;
; Function:  Install SAMSUNG Mobile MTP Device Driver on XP
;
; Copyright (c) DEVGURU Co., LTD. (www.devguru.co.kr)
;******************************************************************************************

[Version]
Signature="$Windows NT$"
Class=WPD
ClassGUID={EEC5AD98-8080-425f-922A-DABF3DE3F69A}
Provider            = %Provider%
DriverVer=02/16/2012,2.9.317.0215
CatalogFile=ssudmtp.cat

[ControlFlags]
ExcludeFromSelect=*

[Manufacturer]
%ssud%          = ssud, NTx86.5.1, NTamd64.5.1

[SSUD.NTx86.5.1]
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685C
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_00
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6862&MI_02

[SSUD.NTamd64.5.1]
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_685C
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6860&MI_00
%USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc%    = ssud.Install, USB\VID_04E8&PID_6862&MI_02


[ssud.Install]
Include = wpdmtp.inf, WINUSB.INF
Needs   = WPD.MTP, WINUSB.NT

[ssud.Install.hw]
Include = wpdmtp.inf
Needs   = WPD.MTP.Registration

[ssud.Install.Services]
Include = wpdmtp.inf
Needs   = WPD.MTP.Services

[ssud.Install.CoInstallers]
Include = wpdmtp.inf
Needs = WPD.MTP.CoInstallers

[ssud.Install.Wdf]
Include = wpdmtp.inf
Needs = WPD.MTP.Wdf
UmdfServiceOrder=WpdMtpDriver

; no sys copyfiles - the sys files are already in place

[Strings]
ssud       = "SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd. "
Provider= "SAMSUNG Electronics Co., Ltd. "
USB\SAMSUNG_MOBILE&MTP.Desc="SAMSUNG Mobile MTP Device"
```

Comment: Your download link says its for W7?

Comment: Did you try updating the driver with the Note connected and showing as unknown device?

Comment: The download link says for lot of OS. I tested it for Win7 and it does not work. For the second comment. The answer is yes. More details: First, official driver from Samsung is installed. Then connected the phone. Wait for all other driver to be installed and for MTP to tail. After that right click and start the step as in my post which result to error.

Comment: EDIT: Wait for all other driver to be installed and for MTP to **fail**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to transfer files from a Samsung device to your computer when it is not being recognized as an MTP is to use Samsung SideSync. Samsung SideSync has the MTP driver built into the program so it will recognize your device as a MTP. I made a video on how to transfer media files with Samsung SideSync:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBXaL8-MPXc

Comment: Could you possibly summarize the content of the video here in case you decide to delete the video in the future?